# Resolving memory address in gdb indirection

Tags: c, pointers, gdb

After compiling with `-g` to get debug info in a program and running in `gdb`, I can do the following to print the argument vector:

```
>>> p __libc_argv
$2 = (char **) 0x7fffffffe9f8
>>> p __libc_argv[0]
$3 = 0x7fffffffec63 "./sample.out"
```

My question is two-fold:

- Why doesn't `__libc_argv[0]` and `__libgc_argv` produce the same memory address? Does `gdb` do some sort of interpretation in the background?
- How could I get the memory address of `0x7fffffffec63` from the above? For example:

  ```
   >>> p __libc_argv
   $2 = (char **) 0x7fffffffe9f8 
   >>> x/s 0x7fffffffec63   <-- how do figure out this memory address value?
   0x7fffffffec63:    "./sample.out"
  ```

Comment: `argv` is a pointer to a pointer. `argv[0]` is the pointer that it points to. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: I don't understand the second question. You get it from `__libc_argv[0]`, exactly how you did it.

Comment: Or `p *__libc_argv`

Comment: `x/s *__libc_argv`?

Comment: @Barmar I see. So then why isn't `argc` and `argv` adjacent to each other? `>>> p __libc_argv
$23 = (char **) 0x7fffffffe9f8` and `>>> p &__libc_argc
$24 = (int *) 0x7ffff7fc0e78 <__libc_argc>`

Comment: What is `&__libc_argv`?

Comment: @Barmar hmm, I think it contains all argv and environmental variables, so it seems to not just be `argv`.

Comment: I meant what is the value of `&__libc_argv`. I'll bet it's adjacent to `&__libc_argc`.

Comment: You're confusing pointer variables with the data they point to. There's no reason for the variable to be near the data.

Comment: @Barmar yea that is it -- it seems they're a `long` away from each other: `>>> x/a &__libc_argv
0x7ffff7fc0e70 <__libc_argv>: 0x7fffffffe9f8
>>> x/d &__libc_argc
0x7ffff7fc0e78 <__libc_argc>: 1`

Comment: @barmar -- `You're confusing pointer variables with the data they point to.` Agreed. Want to post an answer that condenses what you've mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__libc_argv` is a pointer to an array of pointers. `__libc_argv[0]` is the contents of the first element of that array. There's no reason why they should be the same, unless you first did `__libc_argv[0] = __libc_argv` for some reason. But that wouldn't be reasonable, since the elements of `__libc_argv` should be pointers to strings, not pointers to arrays.

On the other hand,  `__libc_argv == &__libc_argv[0]` and `*__libc_argv == __libc_argv[0]`.

To get the address you want, just indirect through `__libc_argv`.

```
>>> x/s *__libc_argv
```